# Why variable initialization is required in ng-init: AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-init

I have started leaning AngularJS.

In AngularJS if we have to initialize an element lets take an example of select:

```
<select id="s1" ng-model="vsrc" ng-init="vsrc='a.mp4'">
    <option value="a.mp4">First video</option>
    <option value="b.mp4">Second video</option>
</select>
```

why initialization of ***vsrc='a.mp4'*** in `ng-init` is required, when I was giving its value like ***ng-init='a.mp4'*** it was not working I had to give like ***ng-init="vsrc='a.mp4'"***. In normal HTML statement we are directly giving default option by providing `value='a.mp4'`

Comment: Because ngInit expects expressions that are evaluated, as every other expression, on the scope. It has nothing to do with ng-model. You should (almost) never use ngInit. Read the documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit

Answer (score 0):

```
<select id="s1" ng-model="vsrc" ng-init="vsrc='a.mp4'"> /*ng-init used to initialize a **variable** before html render, it is a directive which search left and right value always*/
<option value="a.mp4">First video</option> /*value is here as json object {"value":"a.mp4"}*/
<option value="b.mp4">Second video</option>
</select>
```

[take a look over here about ng-init directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit)